# Pack four alpha maps into one

Tags: alpha-blending, alpha

I have read an article about texture splatting that says:

> Because the alphamap only has to be in a single channel of a texture,
>   we can pack up to four alphamaps into a single texture – one in red,
>   one in green, one in blue, and one in alpha.

But it does not mention a way to this. Can anyone tell me or point me to an article on how to do this? I've been googling it the whole afternoon but can't find any. Or maybe I just don't know the correct terms to search. :?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a tool like Photoshop or Gimp to manipulate the channels of an image independently, eg: http://docs.gimp.org/ca/gimp-channel-dialog.html

Comment: That's it! I was actually playing with Gimp's dialog channel last night but can't figure out how to use it properly. Move this as an answer please. Thanks.

Comment: I mean make your comment as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You basically put a one alpha value in each channel.

For example you have `Alpha0 = 0.5`, `Alpha1 = 0.2`, `Alpha2 = 0.7`, `Alpha3 = 1.0`.

The "packed" texture would be `R = 0.5`, `G = 0.2`, `B = 0.7`, `A = 1.0`.

Comment: You just explained what is quoted. I already understand that. What I need is a "how to". For example, I already have 4 individual alpha maps, how can I pack them into one? What tool should I use? Can I do it with gimp? or imagemagick?

Comment: That's a bit broad. Where are you getting the Alpha values from? Where are they gonna be "unpacked" too?

Comment: I'm texturing may model in Blender. Similar to this [link]https://vimeo.com/3837224[/link]. The only difference is I have more that 1 stencil maps(max will be 4). Then I export the stencils as images.

Comment: So you want to create it blender and then use it in blender?

Comment: No, I'm using it in a game engine.

Comment: Blender Game Engine?

Comment: No, Gameplay3D.